# Show $\lim_{x\to3} \frac{2x+3}{4x-9}=3$ by the definition of the limit.

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Show $\lim_{x\to3} \frac{2x+3}{4x-9}=3$ by the definition of the limit.
The definition of the limit: if for any given $\epsilon>0$ $\exists\delta>0$ such that if $x\in D(f(x))$ and $0<|x-c|<\delta$, then $|f(x)-L|<\epsilon$ where $L$ is the limit.

Following an example from the textbook, I have

$|f(x)-3|=\left|\frac{2x+3}{4x-9}-3\right|=\left|\frac{-6x+36}{3(4x-9)}\right|=\frac{6|-x+6|}{3|4x-9|}\cdot\frac{|x-3|}{|x-3|}=\frac{2|-x+6|}{|4x^2-21x+27|}\cdot|x-3|$

Restrict $|x-3|$ to the bounds $1<x<4$.  Then $|f(x)-3|\leq\frac{2|-(4)+6|}{|4(1)^2-21(1)+27|}\cdot|x-3|=\frac{2|2|}{|4-21+27|}\cdot|x-3|=\frac{4}{7}|x-3|$

Choose $\delta(\epsilon)=\inf\{1,\frac{7\epsilon}{4}\}$.  Then, is $0<|x-3|<\delta(\epsilon)$, we have $|f(x)-3|\leq\frac{4}{7}|x-3|<\epsilon$.

Thus, by the definition of the limit, $\lim_{x\to3} \frac{2x+3}{4x-9}=L=3$.

I don't understand what the point of all this was.  You can get the limit by essentially plugging in $x=3$. What exactly is being done? Why do we restrict $|x-3|$ to $1<x<4$? Why choose $\delta(\epsilon)=\inf\{1,\frac{7\epsilon}{4}\}$?
I get that if we end up with a form of $|f(x)-L|<\epsilon$, we then know $L$, but that's about all I grasped.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I put in the full definition from the textbook.

Comment: you  can use the definition for convergence instead.

Comment: The point of doing all that is to rigorously prove that $3$ is the limit. The limit *happens* to be equal to evaluating the function at $3$. But it just *happens* to be that. It is incidental. For most functions evaluating at the point is not the same as the limit. That is why you then have the notion of continuity. You call **continuous** the functions for which limit is the same as evaluation. You give them a name because they are special.

Comment: The assumption of $1<x<4$ is done for convenience. If $x$ is going to be close to $3$ then eventually it is going to be in $1<x<4$. They choose $x<7\epsilon/4$ such that you get the inequality $4|x-3|/7<\epsilon$. They got that $|f(x)-L|<4|x-3|/7$ under the assumption $1<x<4$. This is why they also need to force $|x-3|<1$. That is why they take $\delta=min\{1,7\epsilon/4\}$. So that $\delta$ is both $<1$ and $<7\epsilon/4$

Comment: @user60887 That problem says that the definition of the limit MUST be used. I know how to do this easier ways. But thank you. ^_^

Comment: @ABC Why must $\delta<1$?

Comment: When you force $\delta<1$ you are forcing $|x-3|<\delta<1$. Then $|x-3|<1$, which is the same as saying $1<x<4$. This last was used to get that $|f(x)-3|<4|x-3|/7$.

Comment: @Desperate: You *want* $1 < x < 4$. You get to *choose* $\delta$. If you *choose* $\delta < 1$, then you get what you want!

Comment: "You can get the limit by essentially plugging in x=3."  How do you know?

Answer (score 2):

We have that
$$|f(x)-3|=\left|\frac{2x+3}{4x-9}-3\right|=\left|\frac{10(x-3)}{4x-9}\right|=\frac{10}{|4x-9|}|x-3|.$$
We want to simplify the denominator, ideally getting something like
$$|f(x)-3|<(...)|x-3|.$$
Restrict $x$ to a range around $3$ where $|4x-9|$ is bounded below, like $x\in(\frac{5}{2},\frac{7}{2})$. When $x$ is in that range, $|4x-9|>1$ so that
$$|f(x)-3|<10|x-3|.$$
Therefore if we are given $\epsilon>0$, and we want to provide a $\delta$ such that $|x-3|<\delta$ implies $|f(x)-3|$, we can take
$$\delta=\frac{\epsilon}{10}$$
so that $|f(x)-3|<10|x-3|<\epsilon.$

What about the restriction we placed on $x$? We've already done the hard work. When $\epsilon$ gets small, we have to shrink our interval $(3-\delta,3+\delta)$ so as to not let the function get too big there. We succeeded in quantifying that shrinking: $\delta=\epsilon/10$. When $\epsilon$ gets really big, we don't want to use that formula anymore: it gives us a big $\delta$ which may eventually include the asymptote at $x=9/4$. Fortunately, big $\epsilon$ is satisfied by the $\delta$ from any smaller $\epsilon$. Then we just cut off: if the formula would predict a $\delta>1/2$, don't even bother. Take
$$\delta=\textrm{min}\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{\epsilon}{10}\right).$$

Answer (score 0):

In order to use $\epsilon-\delta$ to make complex arguments, you first need to learn how to use $\epsilon-\delta$ to make simple arguments. Most simple problems can be solved in other ways, but that's just a bonus feature -- it gives us a chance to see how our intuition about the simple problem manifests in the $\epsilon-\delta$ picture. This has two great benefits:

- It gives us practice seeing how to translate our intuitive knowledge into rigorous mathematics that we can manipulate  in less clear contexts.
- It gives us more chances to understand how $\epsilon-\delta$ arguments "work".